# how to skip the condition if it true in php?

Tags: php

I want to skip the condition if it true. I am using if-else statement and my both conditions are true but I want to skip one condition.

Kindly check my code:

```
if (filesize($myFile)>=0) {
// I want to skip this if block. Because files already exists. So this is also true.
}else{
echo "New File Found! Copied The Content.";
//Here I am creating a new file
}
```

In the above code I want to execute only else block and want to skip if block.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome!
Thank You.

Comment: sorry  Sarah, your question is not clear, if condition is true, if block definitely executed. so can you please explain bit more details, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i think you looking for continue;

Answer (score 0):

You can invert your condition. filesize function returns FALSE value in case of an error:

```
if (filesize($myFile) === false) {
    echo "New File Found! Copied The Content.";
}
```

But, the better way is using [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for check exist of a file. For example:

```
if (file_exists($myFile) === false) {
    echo "New File Found! Copied The Content.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how to check filesize>0 or filesize<1

Comment: @Sarah as I can see, you try to check to exist of a file. How want you use checks of file size?

Answer (score 0):

**`1MB` == `1048576` bytes**

**`1MB` == `1024` Kbytes**

**Try this for file size check:**

```
if($_FILES['name']['size'] > 1048576){
  //You can not upload this file
}
```